# Find colour based on brightness in python

Tags: python, colors, rgb

Given a certain amount of brightness (from 0 to 255, for example) is there any algorithm in which one can derive an RGB colour from it?

This would work where 0 is black, 255 is white and all the other colours are placed between them.

Comment: please explain more clearly about your question ? what you want exactly ?

Comment: I would like something of a spectrum, I guess- so that any given number between 0 and 255 is assigned a colour- with the darker colours as smaller numbers and the lighter as larger ones.

Comment: I apologise for the late comment.

Comment: This is not really about python, please read about color spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space. What you want can be achieved by HSL color space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python there is the standard library module [`colorsys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html#module-colorsys). What you want is the [HSL colour coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV); then your "brightness" is the luminance. The values used by the module are 0..1 for each component. [ Notice that whereas the standard order is HSL, in python it is H**LS**. ]

Thus to get fully saturated red colour for different luminances, you can do

```
import colorsys
hue = 0.0        # 0 is red
saturation = 1.0 # fully saturated

for luminance in range(0, 10, 1):
   r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(hue, luminance / 10.0, saturation)
   print('{:d}, {:d}, {:d}'.format(int(r * 255), int(g * 255), int(b * 255)))
```

Resulting in

```
0, 0, 0
51, 0, 0
102, 0, 0
153, 0, 0
204, 0, 0
255, 0, 0
255, 50, 50
255, 101, 101
255, 153, 153
254, 204, 204
255, 255, 255
```

Likewise to get colours at a single brightness for the whole spectrum, keep the luminance and saturation constant, and vary hue from 0 to 1.